# runGdal start date issue

Tags: r-modis

Upon running the following line of code, the download is starting from 2019001 instead of 2015001. How can this be fixed?

```
runGdal(product= "MOD13Q1",begin = "2015001",end = "2020366",tileH = h,tileV = v,SDSstring = B,
        job = "Quality", outProj="GEO", datum="WGS84")
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the output path to a new/different folder under `MODISoptions` solves this issue.